# Extract Summary property from VMM with PowerShell

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, failovercluster, scvmm

I have a `Windows Server 2008R2` running `SCVMM 2012`. I *successfully* removed a virtual machine, according to the *Jobs* output from `VMM`, as seen in this screenshot.

[image]

As you can see, the VM has a red dot indicating a failure. `VMM` doesn't really mention it anywhere. I can only see it as a failed disk under the `Failover Cluster Manager` on any off the cluster nodes.

How can I retrieve this information using `PowerShell`?
If I do:

```
Get-Job -All -Full | Where-Object { $_.Name -contains "Remove virtual machine" }
```

I get a lot of information about this particular job, but I cannot find the *Property*, *Previous Value*, or *New Value* which are listed under the *Summary* tab.
How can I extract these details about this VM?

Answer (score -1):

`-contains` operator should be used for collections(arrays or others) so it is likely you are looking at a wrong object. From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh847759.aspx:

> -Contains
>
> > Description: Containment operator. Tells whether a collection of reference
> >           values includes a single test value. Always returns a Boolean value. Returns TRUE
> >           only when the test value exactly matches at least one of the reference values.

Try this:

```powershell
Get-Job -All -Full | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "Remove virtual machine" }
```

Comment: I understand the difference between `-match` and `-contains` and thanks for pointing that out, but not even this way I can't retrieve the needed information. It returns the same.